std::begin(X) vs. X.begin() for rvalues
For STL-containers, I think the consensus on std::begin is that "std::begin(c) is actually the same as c.begin()". However, according to cppreference, there is no overload for std::begin(C&& c), so if I call std::begin with an rvalue-reference, then the const&-version is called, giving me a C::const_iterator, which seems counter intuitive (why would I not be able to modify an rvalue container?) and disagrees with C::begin() && (which returns a C::iterator):
#include <unordered_map>
#include <type_traits>

using MyMap = std::unordered_map<int, int>;
using Iter = typename MyMap::iterator;
using ConstIter = typename MyMap::const_iterator;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(MyMap().begin()), Iter>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::begin(MyMap())), Iter>); // <-- fails

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(MyMap().begin()), ConstIter>); // <-- fails
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::begin(MyMap())), ConstIter>);

(play with it here)
So I wonder, is this a bug/oversight in the standard/in gcc & clang or am I doing something wrong?
Edit: I am currently using this workaround
  template<class T> concept has_begin = requires (T t) { t.begin(); };

  template<class T>
  decltype(auto) my_begin(T&& x) {
    if constexpr(has_begin<std::remove_reference_t<T>>)
      return std::forward<T>(x).begin();
    else return std::begin(x);
  }

but it seems like a workaround for a bug in the standard, hence the question.
PS: Yes, I am aware that this is an uncommon use-case. Let me propose the following code as a (artificial) example that breaks:
template<class T>
decltype(auto) do_things(T&& in) {
    const auto _end = in.end();
    auto it = std::begin(std::forward<T>(in));
    while(it != _end) {
        it->second += it->first; // fails, even when passing non-const rvalues as 'in'
        ++it;
    }
    return std::forward<T>(in);
}

Now, one might say std::begin(std::forward<T>(in)) should just be std::begin(in) but I have some classes whose begin() && differs largely from their begin() & and I may pass them as in.

IMO both are wrong. It should be returning std::move_iterator or a similar type.

@HolyBlackCat uh, nice, first time I hear of std::move_iterator. It seems exactly what I want here!

you can also look into https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/begin . I know that std::ranges::begin solves some problems with std::begin pertaining to lvalue/rvalue and constness, but I am not familiar with exactly what. It might be what you need.

do_things is somewhat sus. you are forwarding in twice, which means that it's potentially moved-from. You should have std::begin(in) there, in is always an lvalue.

You're right, it's the user's responsability to not use the return result in case that what they passed in becomes unusable after begin() && is called, which may or may not be the case...

No, your library shouldn't be consuming it if it is passing it along

Calling either on an rvalue container is likely a mistake. That container is going to cease to exist at the end of the full expression, and you have no way of referring to it to get an end iterator. std::begin(MyMap()), std::end(MyMap()) is not a valid range, those iterators refer to different objects.
If you have an rvalue reference, then you can use that to provide both ends of a range, but when doing so you have an lvalue.
auto && myMap = MyMap();
std::begin(myMap), std::end(myMap); // <- uses std::begin(MyMap&)


there is a correct use though: std::begin(std::move(myMap)) or it would have been if std::begin were overloaded for &&.

@bolov yes, but that would imply std::end(std::move(myMap)) which isn't wrong, but looks sus.

"likely" is not "necessarily" though.
Indeed, I am writing a heavily templated library and (for complicated reasons) I am calling std::begin(std::forward<T>(x)) alot, which breaks when x is T&&...

@igel why doesn't std::begin(x) work for you? Maybe you want forward_iterator<T>(std::begin(x)), where forward_iterator wraps it in std::move_iterator if T is an rvalue, and passes unchanged when T is an lvalue.

@Caleth I am writing a library that also handles graph traversals and I want to write for(Node u: traversal) so my traversals are "node-containers". However, my traversals may also have a blacklist of nodes to avoid and, normally, they give a reference to this blacklist to their iterators. However, if a traversal goes out of scope, it has to transfer ownership of the blacklist to the iterator. So begin() && differs vastly from begin() & for such traversals.

If your traversals are always classes you control, then you can use std::forward<T>(x).begin(). std::begin exists because arrays don't have member functions.

Yes, but then I can no longer pass C-style arrays of nodes as template parameter...

@igel well in that case you can't, but you could replace any use of a c style array with std::array

@igel also "if a traversal goes out of scope, it has to transfer ownership of the blacklist to the iterator." sounds sus. What about the underlying elements? or are your traversals views?

@Caleth as I said, I'm writing a library. I have no control over what a user of the library might pass to the function and I really don't want to force my users to use std::arrays if they don't want to. I am aware that I can if constexpr ()-check whether the given type has a begin() and that's what I'm currently doing, but it's a workaround for what seems to be a bug in the standard.

@Caleth yes, traversals do not own the nodes, they are merely there to create iterators which themselves observe nodes. I think this counts as a "view" :)
